# Problem with android sign app with multi flavor

Tags: android, gradle, certificate, release, keytool

I try to make auto app sign. I have generated key by command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore app/app_keystore.keystore -alias demo -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
keytool -genkey -v -keystore app/app_keystore.keystore -alias release -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

I have also prepared build.gradle for my Android app:

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    signingConfigs {
        demo {
            try {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['demoAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            } catch (ignored) {
                throw new InvalidUserDataException("Bad credentials")
            }
        }
        release {
            try {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['releaseAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            } catch (ignored) {
                throw new InvalidUserDataException("Bad credentials")
            }
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.app"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode mVersionCode
        versionName mVersionName
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "app_v$versionName")

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    flavorDimensions "server"

    productFlavors {
        demo {
            dimension "server"
            versionName "${mVersionName}.demo"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.demo
        }
        release {
            dimension "server"
            versionName "${mVersionName}.release"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

}
```

These config should return app with certs, but when I check app certificate by command:

```
find . -name "*.apk" -exec echo "APK: {}" \; -exec sh -c 'keytool -printcert -jarfile "{}"' \;
```

I have
`Not a signed jar file`.
I build app by command

```
./gradlew assembleDemoRelease assembleReleaseRelease
```

It looks like app have no cert. When I change password in properties I have an error -- so something is evaluated for generate cert.
Please help me to create app signed. Thank You.

> Blockquote